# AWS Node JS MFA Cognito

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I was working on aws sdk for node js, and trying to authenticate an user from a particular user pool. **NOTE :** my user pool has Multi-factor authentication enabled and receives OTP via SMS.

This is my piece of code : `            var userData = { 
                Username : 'username',
                Pool : userPool
            };

```
        cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

        var authenticationData = {
            Username : 'username',
            Password : 'password',
        };

        var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('authentication successful!')
            },

            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            },

            mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
                var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code' ,'');
                cognitoUser.sendMFACode(verificationCode, this);
            }

        });`
```

**BUT :** the problem is : It gives an error  :

> Error => {"code":"UnknownError",
>               "message":"Unknown error, the response body from fetch is  undefined"}

**And On Stack Trace I Got : ** `Stack Trace : Error
    at Object.onFailure (E:\Karma\node_aws\medium_try\index.js:78:79)
    at E:\Karma\node_aws\medium_try\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\lib\CognitoUser.js:376:31
    at E:\Karma\node_aws\medium_try\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\lib\CognitoUser.js:361:22
    at E:\Karma\node_aws\medium_try\node_modules\amazon-cognito-identity-js\lib\Client.js:114:14
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)`

**BUT AGAIN :::: **The OTP comes to my mobile...

Please can anyone help me????

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the missed callbacks functions so you can handle the state correctly:

```
export interface IAuthenticationCallback {
    onSuccess: (session: CognitoUserSession, userConfirmationNecessary?: boolean) => void,
    onFailure: (err: any) => void,
    newPasswordRequired?: (userAttributes: any, requiredAttributes: any) => void,
    mfaRequired?: (challengeName: any, challengeParameters: any) => void,
    totpRequired?: (challengeName: any, challengeParameters: any) => void,
    customChallenge?: (challengeParameters: any) => void,
    mfaSetup?: (challengeName: any, challengeParameters: any) => void,
    selectMFAType?: (challengeName: any, challengeParameters: any) => void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global['fetch'] = require('node-fetch');
```

Use the above code at the top of your file.